# $parse:ueoe Error in angular js when parsing ng-pattern bound in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that binds a string to apply as an ng-pattern in the directive itself, yet when rendered it gives a UEOE error.

the directive is defined as:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', Directive);

function Directive() {
    var directiveDefinition = {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {          

        },
        scope: { 
            myPattern:'@',
           },

        templateUrl: 'template.htm'
    };
    return directiveDefinition;
}
```

with template

```
<div>
   <form  name=myForm>
        <input type='text' ng-model='ngModel'
               ng-model-options="{ updateOn:'blur', allowInvalid: true }" 
               ng-pattern="{{myPattern}}" /> 
    </form>        
</div>
```

and it is used in a view as:

```
<my-directive ng-model="someValue" my-pattern="[a-z]+"></my-directive>
```

giving the error

> angular.min.js:2 Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$parse/ueoe?p0=%5Ba-z%5D%2B

if I change the regex to have no 'special' characters its fine, but for anything with a complex regex it doesnt work, for example I get a lexerr for the regex [A-Za-z0-9.]+

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%2010-10%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=%5BA-Za-z0-9%5C.%5D%2B

is there a way I can pass such a regex to a directive so that it can be parsed successfully?

Incidentally the ng-pattern works correctly, but other unexpected behavior is seen which I suspect is a knock on effect.

Comment: `ng-pattern="[a-z]+"` generates a $parse:ueoe error. Why would you expect `my-pattern="[a-z]+"` to behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, it seems that ng-patterns expect angular expression and not interpolation in most cased ex `ng-pattern="myPattern"`. Without testing it my self, if using interpolation than the end result has to be regex literal form ex. `/abc/`

From [the api docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern):

> the value is an AngularJS expression:
>      If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly.
>
> If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters. For
>   instance, "abc" will be converted to new RegExp('^abc$').
>
> If the value is a RegExp literal, e.g. ngPattern="/^\d+$/", it is used directly.

ngPattern

> AngularJS expression that must evaluate to a RegExp or a String
>   parsable into a RegExp, or a RegExp literal. See above for more
>   details.